# SQL Azure doesn't support 'select into' - Is there another way?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a very complicated table I'd like to take a temporary backup of whilst I make some changes. Normally, I'd just do the following:

```
SELECT  *
INTO    temp_User
FROM    dbo.[User] AS u
```

Unfortunately I'm using Azure, and it appears this isn't supported:

> Msg 40510, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Statement 'SELECT INTO' is not
>   supported in this version of SQL Server.

Is there a way to re-create this feature into a function, potentially? I could do this by scripting the table, creating it and  then inserting data using a select statement but given how frequently I use Azure, and how many databases I need to work on in this area this is very unwieldy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new [Azure DB Update preview](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new/) has this problem resolved:

> The V12 preview enables you to create a table that has no clustered
>   index. This feature is especially helpful for its support of the T-SQL
>   SELECT...INTO statement which creates a table from a query result.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new/

Answer (score 8):

Azure requires a clustered index on all tables, therefore `SELECT INTO` is not supported.

You'll have to:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_User () --fill in table structure
INSERT INTO temp_User
SELECT *
FROM dbo.[User]
```

To script table easily you can write your own or use one of the answers to this question:

[Script CREATE Table SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table/317864#317864)

**Update:**  As Jordan B pointed out, V12 will include support for heaps (no clustered index requirement) which means `SELECT INTO` will work.  At the moment V12 Preview is available, Microsoft of course only recommends upgrading with test databases.

Comment: Sure, I understand this and mentioned it in my original question - but is  there a way to re-create this process (perhaps using system tables?)

Comment: this is not really a replacement for the CTAS or even a workaround but rather "well it's not supported"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it cant be done. Here is how I worked around it:

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Right click on the table
3. Select Script as ... Create Table
4. Edit the generated script to change the table name to what you specified in your query
5. Execute your query

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO temp_User
SELECT * FROM dbo.[User]
```

You can try the above. It's basically a select that is applied to an insert statement

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/10/sql-server-use-insert-into-select-instead-of-cursor/

Comment: Syntactically incorrect? And I don't think you meant insert into?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have a table with Id, Column1 and Column2. Then this could be your solution

```
CREATE TABLE YourTableName_TMP ....
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTableName_TMP ON 
GO
INSERT INTO YourTableName_TMP
([Id] ,[Column1] ,[Column2])      
SELECT [Id] ,[Column1] ,[Column2]
FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  [Id] ,[Column1] ,[Column2] ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM YourTableName
    )
    WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 500000
)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTableName_TMP OFF
GO
```

First you create a temporary table and then you insert rows windowed. It's a mess, I know. My experiences are, that executing this using SQL Server Management Studio from a client makes approximately 200.000 rows a minute.

Answer (score 0):

As wrote above - you need to rewrite your query from using **select into** to **create table** like

It is my sample. Was :

```
        select  emrID, displayName --select into
        into #tTable
        from emrs

        declare @emrid int
        declare @counter int = 1
        declare @displayName nvarchar(max)

        while exists (select * from #tTable)
        begin
            -- some business logic
            select top 1  @displayName = displayname
            from #tTable
            group by displayname
            update emrs  set groupId = @counter where @displayName = displayname    
            delete #tTable
            where @displayName = displayname
            set @counter = @counter + 1 
        end
        drop table #tTable
```

Modified :

```
        CREATE TABLE #tTable ([displayName] nvarchar(max)) --create table
        INSERT INTO #tTable -- insert to next select  :

        select  displayName            
        from emrs

        declare @emrid int
        declare @counter int = 1
        declare @displayName nvarchar(max)

        while exists (select * from #tTable)
        begin
            -- some business logic
            select top 1  @displayName = t.displayName
            from #tTable as t
            group by t.displayname
            update emrs  set groupId = @counter where @displayName = displayname    
            delete #tTable
            where @displayName = displayname
            set @counter = @counter + 1 
        end
        drop table #tTable
```

Do not forget to drop your temp table.
Also, you can find more simple example with description here : 
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/statement-select-into-is-not-supported-in-this-version-of-sql-server