# Does Azure SQL now support CTAS (select .. into, insert into .. select .. , etc)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

An old 2012 post said AzureSQL needs clustered indexes so that `CTAS` was not supported: [SQL Azure doesn't support 'select into' - Is there another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818394/sql-azure-doesnt-support-select-into-is-there-another-way)

Is there support for this in 2024?

Comment: The linked post also states that support will be added in version 12, in 2015, so it does, in fact, tell you it is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Create Table As Select (CTAS) is not supported yet:

[image]

But SELECT INTO is definitely supported.

[image]

Comment: I see what happened: I had been aleady trying `select .. into` and there was an error that said `Syntax error near INTO` . But it was due to an unrelated error (unmatched  `case .. end`.

Comment: Sometimes T-SQL error messages are misleading.  I glad you found what really originated the error message.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)